# Nested for loops - is it possible to execute each once and then jump to next object?

Tags: python

I need to execute each loop only once to each object present in container rows and rows2. Depends on the place where I put break statement I can execute rows or rows2 objects, but never both. rows and rows2 are fetchall(). I cannot find out how to insert the each object only once avoiding multiplying it. Appreciate for help.

```
for row in rows:
    for row2 in rows2:
        ProductList.insert(END,row+row2,str(''))
        break
```

Comment: Do rows and rows2 have a one to one correspondence? If they do use a single loop, no breaks and `for row, row2 in zip(rows, rows2):`

Comment: @Dan you are a star mate :) Did not now about zip thing. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rows` and `rows2` have a one-to-one correspondence, then use a single loop:

```
for row, row2 in zip(rows, rows2):
    ProductList.insert(END, row + row2, '')
```

Comment: thanks again Dan. By the way I'm just curious - Is it possible to get the same effect as above using the 2 indenpendent loops as I did try before ?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it using a nested loop. A less pythonic solution that would be more familiar in other languages (i.e. don't do this) might be `for idx in range(len(rows)): ProductList.insert(END, rows[idx] + rows2[idx], '')`

Answer (score 0):

You could also exploit a while loop as:

```
nobject = 0
while nobject < 10:
    for row2 in rows2:
                ProductList.insert(END,nobject+row2,str(''))
    nobject += 1
```